# Chrome doesnt respond as expected to @media query

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I'm building a responsive website and ran into a problem with Chrome not implementing @media query the same as Firefox.

On the image, Firefox is to the left (how I expect the design to look) and Chrome on the right. As you can see Chrome don't change according to the @media query. Same on mobile devices.

**CSS**:

@media-medium-width: 768px;

```
.bm-s-section-ill-wrap-item {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid @dark-blue;
    flex: 1 1 48%;

    @media(min-width: @media-medium-width) {
        margin: 6px;
        border-width: 4px;
        flex: 1 1 32%;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are not using valid CSS. You can't use variables or nest selectors like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
.bm-s-section-ill-wrap-item {
     max-width: 100%;
     margin: 2px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     border: 2px solid @dark-blue;
     flex: 1 1 48%;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
     .bm-s-section-ill-wrap-item {
          margin: 6px;
          border-width: 4px;
          flex: 1 1 32%;
      }
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding screen and moving the @media query to the root of the css and changing the style, but it stays the same. I use less to generate the css files and the css itself is not incorrect and works as expected on Firefox, but maybe Chrome has a different implementation..

Comment: @TheRuler The CSS you included just simply is *not standard CSS*, regardless of how you generated it or what developer addons you have in FF to support it.

Comment: One of the best ways to do this is to use the bootstrap. It's very convenient to use . https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Comment: @TheRuler "*ok.. got a solution?*" - yes. **Use valid CSS**. You're already using SASS so just used the compiled CSS instead of the scss file.

Comment: it's just a little strange it works on firefox but not chrome. but I'll do some changes and see what I get

Comment: @TheRuler It might work on *your* Firefox, but it doesn't work in FF by default. You must have an addon installed in your FF that can read SCSS.

Comment: nope. I use an addon to visual studio that generates the css files from less. so both firefox and chrome uses the same css